# разобрать изменить и собрать

Tags: java, android

Месяцев 3 назад собрал приложение.никаких бд и ничего нет .чтото легкое .Проект сам утерян  .теперь мне надо както сделать пару изменеий в проекте заменить текст и тд.Не знаю что делать ?можно ли как то декомпилоровать апк изменить данные и обратно компелировать ?

Очень нужна ваша помощ

Comment: приложение находится на Google Play?

Comment: Нет  я его не выставлял туда ю но должен сегодня

Comment: у менять есть апк только

Comment: или можно как то декомпилировать и взять оттуда мои данные и копи пастом создать новый проект

Answer (score 6, accepted):

для проведения таких действий вам потребуется:

- **dex2jar**
- **Java Decompiler**
- **ApkTool**

Далее выполнить по следующим шагам:

1. Качаем **dex2jar** и извлекаем в папку, например `С:\Decompile` .
2. Качаем **Java Decompiler** (например JD-GUI) и извлекаем файлы для удобства в ту же папку, куда и dex2jar.
3. Качаем **apktool** и **apktool-install-windows-r04-brut1.tar.bz2** и извлекаем файлы уже в системную папку. По умолчанию `C:\Windows`. (Не забыть скачать второй архив)
4. Берем нужный `apk файл` и кладем в папку с **dex2jar** и **Java Decompiler**.
5. Открываем Командную строку (Обработчик команд Windows) в вышеупомянутой папке (В папке по пустому месте при зажатой кнопке Shift нажимаем правую кнопку мыши и выбираем Обработчик команд Windows).
6. Вводим команду `dex2jar <ваш apk файл>` и если все прошло хорошо, в той же папке появится файл `<название вашего файла>.apk.dex2jar.jar`
7. Запускаем **jd-gui** и открываем полученный на предыдущем шаге файл. (На Windows 7 открывать с правами администратора и с совместимостью Windows XP SP3)
8. Выбираем пункт меню `File-Save All Source`s и сохраняем.
9. Извлекаем полученный zip архив.
10. Помещаем полученную папку в папку src (надо предварительно создать).(Что бы получилась примерно такая структура `С:\Decompile\<название вашего файла>\src\com\android`)
11. Опять же в командной строке вводим команду `apktool d <название вашего файла>.apk <название вашего файла>`, где `<название вашего файла>.apk`-имя пакета, <название вашего файла>-папка для декомпиляции.

Если все хорошо, тогда в указанной папке будут исходники в двух форматах (java и smali), ресурсы и файлы `AndroidManifest.xml`, `apktool.yml`

Таким образом будут получены исходники. Правда после декомпиляции в коде есть, можно сказать, ошибки,например вместо true и false стоят 1 и 0 соответственно.

Comment: Я сделал апк винрар и открыл его нашел все что мне нужно ,теперь осталось толко найти файл gradle где добавляю  библиотеки через compile  незнаете к нему путь ?

Comment: Вообще для того вам нужно среду разработки вернуть разобранный apk; полученный код например передать в IDE Eclipse (File-Import) нужно поместить архив в папку с проектом, предварительно изменив на третьей строке <name>PROJECT NAME</name> PROJECT NAME на желаемое название, в файле .project . Это связано с тем, что, если я правильно помню, gradle - это в android studio система сборки. Если же использовать eclipse без gradle, тогда antenna - препроцессор для java.

Comment: Либо как вариант, если нужен gradle, верните декомпилированный проект в android Studio:apk-tool'ом декомпилируете, далее в студио "Open an existing Android Studio project" и указать путь к каталoгу декомпилированного приложения.